# Can I play warcraft 3 cinematics in game? focal

Tags: wine, games, mono

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal) .
Is there any way to play warcraft 3 cinematics in game?
My version is  Warcraft 3 Complete v1.25 (chaos+frozen).
I don't use Lutris.
The game works well after installing **mono** this way before installing the game:

```
 :~$ winetricks dotnet45
```

All well except cinematics. There sound but with only blank screen. They can be played with VLC from **~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Warcraft III Complete/Movies/**. The two first seem to be:*TutorialIn.mpq* then *TutorialOp.mpq*.

I've set wineconfig to simulate a virtual desktop set to me screen size(1280x1024) and windows version to windowsXP, but no change.
Not a too hard problem but I like to know if there is a solution.

Using winehq PPA:

```
:~$ wine --version
wine-7.0.1
```

log:

```
:~$ wine '~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Warcraft III Complete/Warcraft III.exe'
0074:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0x48bd0, 0): stub
0074:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0000000000010020, 0000000000048BD0): stub
0024:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0x4637a8, 1): stub
0024:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (00010052, 004637A8): stub
0118:err:ole:com_get_class_object apartment not initialised
0118:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
0118:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0x4ab4b8, 1): stub
0118:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0003007E, 004AB4B8): stub
0124:fixme:d3d:state_linepattern_w Setting line patterns is not supported in OpenGL core contexts.
0118:err:system:NtUserChangeDisplaySettings Changing (null) display settings returned -2.
[FAIL] pivw->put_Owner(NULL) = -21474672620198:fixme:d3d:state_linepattern_w Setting line patterns is not supported in OpenGL core contexts.
0118:err:system:NtUserChangeDisplaySettings Changing (null) display settings returned -2.
[FAIL] pivw->put_Owner(NULL) = -2147467262[FAIL] pivw->put_Owner(NULL) = -214746
726201ac:fixme:d3d:state_linepattern_w Setting line patterns is not supported in OpenGL core contexts.
0118:fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (150591A0) stub
018c:err:virtual:virtual_setup_exception stack overflow 128 bytes in thread 018c addr 0x7bc55d3d stack 0x9d40f80 (0x9d40000-0x9d41000-0x9e40000)
018c:err:virtual:virtual_setup_exception nested exception on signal stack in thread 018c addr (nil) stack 0x7fe1f49
```